# Build a dictionary with multiple arrays(for each key) from a dictionary with only one array(for each key)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have the dictionary `d` where, for each key, all values are stored in one array

```
d = {'0': [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], '1': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], '2': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], '3': [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], '4': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
```

and the dictionaries

```
d1 = {'0': ('2',), '1': ('1', '3', '4'), '2': ('1', '3', '4'), '3': ('2', '4'), '4': ('2', '3', '5')}
d2 = {'0': ('1', '3', '4'), '1': ('2', '4'), '2': ('2', '3', '5'), '3': ('2', '3', '5'), '4': ('4',)}
```

I would like to build the dictionary `data` which contains the same keys and values in the dictionary `d` but the stored values are divided into many arrays(depending on the key) instead of only one array!

So, the dictionary `d` will be transformed to the dictionary `data` by using the lengths of `d1` and `d2`.

**How?** For each key, the values will be divided into `(len(d1[key]) + len(d2[key]))` arrays where each array will contain `(len(d1[key]) * len(d2[key]))` values.

For example,

`d['0']= [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`.

Since `len(d1['0'])=1` and  `len(d2['0'])=3` then

`data['0'] = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]`

I've been trying but really I don't have an idea how to do it! i.e how to store the first `(len(d1[key]) * len(d2[key]))` values in an array and to move after that to the next `(len(d1[key]) * len(d2[key]))` values and store them in an array and once I have the `(len(d1[key]) + len(d2[key]))` arrays to store them as values for the key!

This what I did but it is not giving me the wanted dictionary!

```
data = defaultdict(list)
first_data = [] #array contains len(d1[key])*len(d2[key]) values
second_data = [] #array contains len(d1[key])+len(d2[key]) arrays
for key in constraints:
    for values in range( (len(d1[key])*len(d2[key])) * (len(d1[key])+len(d2[key])) ):
       for values in range(len(d1[key])*len(d2[key])):
          first_data.append(values)
       values += values
       second_data.append(first_data)  
    data[key] = second_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lens = {k: len(d1[k])*len(d2[k]) for k in d1}
data = {k: [a[i:i+lens[k]] for i in range(0, len(a), lens[k])]
        for k, a in d.items()}
```

Or without precalculated `lens`.

```
data = {k: [a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)] 
        for k, a in d.items() for n in [len(d1[k])*len(d2[k])]}
```